# How to change table alias in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to show employee's first name from employee table, but when I execute the query it always returns this error

> **#1066 - Not unique table/alias**

This is my query:

```
SELECT `employee`.`Fname`
FROM `employee`
LEFT JOIN `company07`.`employee`
ON `employee`.`Ssn` = `employee`.`Super_ssn`
ORDER BY `employee`.`Fname` ASC
```

Q: Why is MySQL returning error 1066?

Q: How do I change the table alias to avoid error 1066?

Comment: this syntax is just wrong, would need to see the table strucure\relationships to give you the right syntax

Comment: NB: phpmyadmin is NOT a database, just another php script

Comment: Your `on` doesn't make sense. Why join `on` the same columns of a table? Also is `company07` a database or table?

Comment: i just copy-paste it from the update query section on phpmyadmin which i just change the column to 'employee'.'Fname'

Comment: yes company07 is the database

Comment: You need to define the databases and tables then for each. It is unclear which db your `employee` is matching with.

Comment: Fname| Minit| Lname |Ssn | Bdate |Address |Sex |Salary| Super_ssn| Dno|
John B Smith 123456789 1965-01-09 731 Fondren, Houston, TX M 30000.00 333445555 [->] 5 [->]
franklin B wong 333445555 1988-05-22 638 voss, houston, TX M 40000.00 888665555 [->] 5 [->]

Comment: I don't what that data is. Please update the question.

Comment: if you just want Fname from employee, with no where clauses why do you need to join ? `SELECT Fname FROM employee ORDER BY Fname ASC`

Comment: @nogad I think OP is using 2 databases with the same table names.. not really clear yet though.

Comment: @chris85 your random guess is as good as mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two table references with the same name "`employee`". And this isn't valid.

The workaround is to assign an *alias* to one of the table references. That will make the names *unique*.

Frequently, we assign a short alias to *every* table reference. And we use that alias to qualify the column references.

In the following example, we assign the alias `e` to one of the tables, and the alias `c` to the other.

```
 SELECT e.`fname`
   FROM `employee` e
   LEFT 
   JOIN `company07`.`employee` c
     ON c.`ssn` = e.`super_ssn`
  ORDER
     BY e.`fname` ASC
```

I just guessed which table "`ssn`" is from and which table "`super_ssn`" is from.  In the original query, it's ambiguous. Both are qualified with the table name `employee`. But we don't know which of the tables is being referred to. MySQL has the same problem... which table does "employee" refer to.  And this is why MySQL requires that every table name (or alias) needs to be unique.

Comment: should that be  "JOIN `company07` c" can you use  a column in the join? and as no data is being selected from company07, nor is it used in any condition, its pointless

Comment: @nogad: the original query referenced **company07.employee**.  I interpreted that the same way MySQL would interpret it... **database_name.table_name_or_view_name**. I didn't meant to suggest that I understand what OP is attempting to achieve. And I didn't mean to suggest I have some clairvoyant visibility to the databases, tables and columns being referenced.) I was only offering an explanation of the error, what MySQL is complaining about. As a demonstration of how to avoid that error, I gave an example of a SQL statement that doesn't raise that error, based on the original OP statement.

Comment: well you could just wait for clarification, i dont see how random guessing helps any one.

Comment: @nogad:  I took the question to be akin to "Why is MySQL returning Error 1066?" and/or "How do I modify my query to change the alias (to avoid the error)". Those are the questions I saw, and those are the questions I answered. It seems like you're suggesting OP wasn't asking the specific questions I answered, but OP is asking a question that's not possible to discern, and an attempt to answer that question is *random guessing*.)